# StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot create Standard connected accounts with capabilities via API

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to test out building accounts in test mode on stripe connect and I am running into an error when I ping the node endpoint. It seems to be related to my account settings but I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. Appreciate the help. Below is a sample of the code:

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
//const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: resolve("../../.env") });
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_....");

app.use(express.static("../../client"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const path = resolve("../../client/index.html");
  res.sendFile(path);
});



// Part 1: hosted Connect Custom Onboarding
app.post("/create-account-hosted", async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  try {
    // Create account
    var account = await stripe.accounts.create({
      Country: 'US',
      type: 'custom',
      //business_type: 'individual',
      //requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],

     
    });

    // Create accountLink
    var accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      account: account.id,
      success_url: 'http://localhost:4242?success',
      failure_url: 'http://localhost:4242?failure',
      type: 'custom_account_verification',
      collect: 'eventually_due'
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400)
    res.send({ error: err })
    return;
  }
  res.send(accountLink);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('LISTENING AT PORT 4242...'));
```

I get the following error:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot create Standard connected accounts with capabilities via API.
```

I believe I have set up my account right. My account looks as follows on the connect page:

[image]

Comment: The parameters you passed in account.create seems wrong, you should use 
 ` capabilities: {
    card_payments: {requested: true},
    transfers: {requested: true},
  },`

Comment: Thank you, I also had to make Country lowercase. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Maybe must be standard change to custom.  Type custom can have with data account